# how to make - react seek bar

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using react and transitions to animate movement according to time stamp (lighting up of boxes), i need to have a "slider" functionality to allow me to seek to a certain point in time

(each box represents a js object with a corresponding "created_at" time stamp (iso time string)

example : https://v4.mui.com/components/slider/

any good react tools or libraries to best handle this visualization use case

heres my created layout:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/972RA.png)

Answer (score -2):

I think CSS transitions might be useful for transitions https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_transitions/Using_CSS_transitions

Please check react slider as well https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-slider